# Attempting to insert an integer from a list into datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, range

What I am trying to accomplish is very simple: creating a loop from a range (pretty self explanatory below) that will insert the month into the datetime object. I know %d requires an integer, and I know that 'month' type is int...so I'm kind of stuck as to why I can't substitute my month variable.   Here is my code:

```
all_months=range(1,13)
for month in all_months:
    month_start = (datetime.date(2010,'%d',1))%month
    next_month_begin= datetime.date(2010,'%d',1)%(month+1)  
    month_end=next_month_begin - timedelta(days=1)
    print month_start                                        
    print month_end
```

What am I doing wrong?

All help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to fix here.

EDIT: First, be careful with your range, since you are using month+1 to create next_month_begin, you do not want this to be greater than 12 or you will get an error.

Next, when you are trying to create the date object you are passing the month in as a string when you use `(datetime.date(2010,'%d',1))%month`.  Your code probably throwing this error `TypeError: an integer is required`.

You need to give it the integer representing the month, not a string of the integer (there is a difference between `1` and `'1'`).  This is also a simple fix, since you have variable named `month` that is already an integer, just use that instead of making a string.  So you code should be something like:

`month_start = datetime.date(2010,month,1)`

I think you can figure out how to apply this to your `next_month_begin` assignment.

The last problem is that you need to use `datetime.timedelta` to tell Python to look in the `datetime` module for the `timedelta()` function -- your program would currently give you an error saying that timedelta is not defined.

Let me know if you have any problems applying these fixes.  Be sure to include what the error you may be getting as well.

Comment: whoops, my mistake, it was the month+1 that was causing problems, thanks

Comment: Great! Everything works fine with these fixes except for the fact (which you noted) that datetime does not accept the number 13...am trying to resolve this issue. Would I have to include an exception for December, stating that it simply iterates until the 31st? Or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: The datetime module, unfortunately, does not allow you to use timedelta() to add a month to your date and since months do not have the same number of days it is tricky.  I think that probably the easiest way is to just check if the month is 12 and then add a special case for 12/31.  This is probably not the most clean way but it should serve your goals.  Also feel free to vote up any answers that were helpful to you.

Comment: Much appreciated, swanson- mil gracias ('a thousand thanks,' en espanol)

Comment: de nada :) good luck continuing with python - its a fun language

Answer (score 2):

You've got other answers, but here's a way to get the last day of the month.  Adding 31 days will get you into the next month regardless of the number of days in the current month, then moving back to the first and subtracting a day will give the ending date.

```
import datetime
for month in range(1,13):
    month_start = datetime.date(2010,month,1)
    into_next_month = month_start + datetime.timedelta(days=31)
    month_end = into_next_month.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print month_start,month_end
```

Answer (score 0):

`month` is a variable and you can use it to create the datetime object. I think you want to do the following:

```
month_start = datetime.date(2010, month, 1)
next_month_begin = datetime.date(2010, month+1, 1)
```

That will work, because datetime.date() requires 3 integer arguments. `'%d' % month` would instead format the integer `month` as string. `'%04d' % 3` for example would format the number 3 with 4 digits and leading zeros. But it's important to know, that even the (nearly unformatted) string `"3"` is different to the number `3` in Python.

And you can't write `datetime(...) % 3` because the `%` operator will only work when used on a format string like the previous `"%03d" % 3` example and not on a datetime object.

But other types might also accept the `%` operator (not including datetime objects). For example, integers accept the `%` operator to get the remainder of a division: `3 % 2 # returns 1`. But there, the meaning of `%` is completely different, because the meaning of the operator depends on the types involved. For example, try `3 + 2` and `"3" + "2"`. There, the meaning of `+` differs (integer addition vs. string concatenation), because the types are different too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the calendar module (http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html).

It has batteries included for this sort of thing...

You could just do:

```
from calendar import Calendar
def start_and_end_days(year, month):
    cal = Calendar()
    month_days = [day for day in cal.itermonthdays(year, month) if day.month == month]
    first_day = month_days[0]
    last_day = month_days[-1]
    return (first_day, last_day)
```